# Can too many vias be counterproductive? (via stitching)

Tags: pcb-design, via

I am designing a PCB where some traces run a lot of current, so I have these traces duplicated on the other layer and do via stitching.

Now I am wondering if it can be counter productive to put down as many vias as possible, because the holes subtract from the conducting path. Is this correct? If yes, is there a sweetspot for how many vias to use?

Comment: 2 layer design?

Comment: Cost? For low volume production, some (most of the ones I’ve been using) have a number of vias per area number. If you go above it, they want extra payment. If below, just add as many as you need.

Comment: the sweetspot is zero vias along the path and only put several at places where the current has to be forced to a single layer, i.e. typically the beginning and end of this trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for any vias along the path of the two traces.
Assume the two sides of the PCB are symmetrical and also the connection to source and sink of the current are equally well connected to both sides.
In this case, the current will be equal and the voltage drop will be the same at any position on the PCB. If you now add a via the potential on both sides of the via will be the same and therefore there will be no current in the PCB.

The main thing you need make sure is that the two sides carry equal currents. You can do this by adding a couple of vias right next to the source and the sink.

Like you say, if you add more vias you will reduce the width of the traces due to the holes (unless you go the expensive way of plugging and capping the vias). The additional copper inside the PCB can't compensate for this.
The amount of reduction will be less than the hole size - the current can instead flow on the walls of the vias as well reducing the effect.

If you're working in a high-frequency environment (e.g. >100 MHz) the situation will be more complex and needs to be evaluated in detail.

Comment: thanks, that makes total sense! the source is connected to both sides, but the sink is an SMD part. I will now just put some vias on the sink pad :)

Comment: @Donnerbraten Vias on the pad directly can cause some issues in automatic assembly lines and using solder paste. The paste flows into the holes and not enough stays on the pad to connect to the component. Better place the vias a millimeter outside the pad.

Comment: I am hand soldering these boards, so this wont be a problem. I placed 4 vias around the pad and 2 on the pad like this: [link]/https://ibb.co/7Q4C7LT(

Answer (score 4):

Contact your PCB fabricator to understand the current carrying load that a via of a particular size can carry.

All vias are not the same.  Diameter of the hole and plating thickness of the hole plays a huge role in determining the current.

After you have the plating thickness and select a hole diameter, you can start making voltage drop calculations and heating (power loss) for different numbers of holes.  These calculations are called "engineering".  It takes work and there are not "rules of thumb" for every situation.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 most important things on power traces is resistance with temprise and inductance for switched currents for impedance rise and resonance.

Consult with Sierra PCB design tools and/or consider busbars or braid or globs of solder to lower temp rise to below max. Ambient specs. Overall.  If no high currents are switched and V=LdI/dt does not matter, then ignore the following.

Inductance/capacitance ratio is the square of characteristic impedance.

Inductance is proportional to the log of length/diameter ratio and in parallel 1/L=1/(n*L.via), thus the inductance reduces with n vias.  This gives the nominal L of 1nH/mm for a certain ratio and DCR depends on wall thickness and gap.

The smaller the ground/power plane gap the lower the impedance the better the decoupling of switched FET capacitance. Usually very smooth copper and very thin prepreg are needed to have adequate breakdown voltage but excellent results.

- there was one supplier who specialized in the above process

Otherwise the quality of your power planes depends on the bandwidth if the noise with a series resonant frequency and Q can be computed L(C)^0.5=T , X(f)/R=Q.

The capacitance per square depends on area/gap ratio.

in order to compute the optimal vias, both Z and f.max or 1/4 wavelength must be defined and often 10 vias per 1/4wave are used.

Comment: How does this answer the question? That was about conductance of traces, not inductance, capacitance, breakdown voltage or high frequency behavior.

Comment: How do you know what the dI/dt is? That also affects impedance. Parallel grounds or power tracks don't need any vias if they are already parallel at source and end points for resistance by any means including connectors.

Comment: Did you read the question? The way the vias are suggested to be placed has no influence on inductance.